# Recursive query in Hive

Tags: dictionary, recursion, hive, reduce

Hive support with clause, but hive does not support Recursive Queries.
In relational databases, there is some recursive function, stored procedure to do recursive query but hive does not support stored procedures and recursive function.
how we can achieve recursive query in hive?

Comment: See this: https://www.pythian.com/blog/recursion-in-hive/

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can set two property as true to have recursive queries in hive session

hive> set mapred.input.dir.recursive = true;

hive> set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories = true;

These two values works in conjunction.